# Webkit WebView not able to connect to motion-notify-event

Tags: webkit, gtk, webview, mouseevent

I want to retrieve the position of mouse pointer in webkit's webview widget. So I tried to connect it like this.

```
gtk_signal_connect (GTK_OBJECT (gtk_widget_get_toplevel(web_view)), "motion-notify-event",
                      (GtkSignalFunc) motion_notify_event, NULL);
```

But the callback functions gets never called when mouse moves or any other time. 
The same experiment works with gtkentry. Any idea on what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but you can try adding `GDK_POINTER_MOTION_MASK` to the webview's accepted events using `gtk_widget_add_events()`.

PS. Don't use `gtk_signal_connect`; it's old and will be removed in GTK 3. You should connect your signal like this:

```
g_signal_connect(gtk_widget_get_toplevel(web_view), "motion-notify-event", G_CALLBACK(motion_notify_event), NULL);
```